# Переопределение магических методов стандартных классов int и float

Tags: python, классы, методы

ㅤㅤ У меня есть класс `A` с магическими методами сложения, вычитания и так далее. Эти магические методы класса `А` преобразуют передаваемый `other` (который может быть `int` или `float`) в экземпляр класса `A` (для вычислений). И я спокойно могу складывать `A` с переданным `other`, какого типа он бы не был (в противном случае - эксепшэн)

```
## Рабочий класс с определёнными магическими методами
class A:

    ## Магический метод, вызываемый при str(A())
    def __str__(self):
        return '"%s"' % (self.s)

    ## Магический метод сложения (+)
    def __add__(self, other):
        # other должен быть преобразован в тип A по-любому, иначе эксепшн
        if not isinstance(other,A):
            other=A(other)
        return A(self.s+other.s) # Возврат нового экземпляра A, после операции сложения двух экземпляров

    ## Класс инициализации
    def __init__(self,s:float):
        # Создание нужных атрибутов...
        self.s=float(s)

# Запуск скрипта, если это самостоятельный запуск
if __name__=='__main__':
    r1=A(7) # Экземпляр класса A
    r2=A(4) # Экземпляр класса A
    r3=10   # Тип int
    print(r1+r2) # Напечатается "11.0"
    print(r2+r3) # Напечатается "14.0" (этот int преобразовался в экземпляр класса A в вызванном методе __add__ класса A)
    print(r3+r2) # Эксепшэн TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'A'
```

ㅤㅤ Однако, есть проблема. я не могу сложить `int` с `A`, так как вызывается `__add__` класса `int`. И выдает ошибку. Пробовал переопределить поведение таким образом, чтобы принудительно складывать `A` с `int` при попытке сложить `int` с `A`:

```
# Переопределение поведения класса int при вызове __add__
class int(int):
    def __add__(self, x:A):
        return x+self

m1=A(4)   # Экземпляр класса A
m2=int(10)
m3=10
print(m2+m1) # Печатает "14.0"
print(m3+m1) # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'A'
```

ㅤㅤ Однако поведение странное: если после такого переопределения инициализировать `int(10)`, всё будет хорошо, но просто написав `10`, будет снова вызвано исключение.

ㅤㅤ Возможно ли корректно добавлять магические методы в стандартные классы? Чтобы было возможным складывать `int` с `A` или `float` с `A` и любой другой встроенный класс c `A`. Или какое решение будет более рациональным?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `__radd__`:

```
class A:

    def __str__(self):
        return '"%s"' % (self.s)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other,A):
            other=A(other)
        return A(self.s+other.s)
    
    # Выполняется, если экземпляр класса является вторым слагаемым
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self + other

    def __init__(self,s:float):
        self.s=float(s)


r1=A(7)
r2=A(4)
r3=10
print(r1+r2)
print(r2+r3)
print(r3+r2) # И никакого экзепшна!
```

Если у первого слагаемого нет своего `__add__`, а у второго слагаемого есть `__radd__`, то выполнится именно он.

Comment: в данном случаr можно просто `__radd__  = __add__`